# I'm unable to change the array of an existing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change one value inside a nested state.

I have a state called `toDoItems` that is filled with data with `componentDidMount`

The issue is that changing the values work and I can check that with a `console.log` but when I go to `setState` and then `console.log` the values again it doesn't seem like anything has changed?

This is all of the code right now

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toDoItems: null,
      currentView: "AllGroup"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch("/data.json")
      .then(items => items.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          toDoItems: [...data],
        });
      })
  };

  changeToDoItemValue = (givenID, givenKey, givenValue) => {
    console.log(this.state.toDoItems);
    let newToDoItems = [...this.state.toDoItems];
    let newToDoItem = { ...newToDoItems[givenID - 1] };
    newToDoItem.completedAt = givenValue;
    newToDoItems[givenID - 1] = newToDoItem;
    console.log(newToDoItems);
    this.setState({
     toDoItems: {newToDoItems},
    })
    console.log(this.state.toDoItems);
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.toDoItems) {
      // console.log(this.state.toDoItems[5 - 1]);
      return (
        <div>
          {
            this.state.currentView === "AllGroup" ?
              <AllGroupView changeToDoItemValue={this.changeToDoItemValue}/> :
              <SpecificGroupView />
          }

        </div>
      )
    }
    return (null)
  };
}

class AllGroupView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 onClick={() => this.props.changeToDoItemValue(1 , "123", "NOW")}>Things To Do</h1>
        <ul className="custom-bullet arrow">
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So with my `console.log` I can see this happening

`console.log(this.state.toDoItems);`

[image]

and then with `console.log(newToDoItems)`

[image]

and then again with `console.log(this.state.toDoitems)` after `setState`

[image]

Comment: setState is async, so trying to evaluate the state just after setting it will just return you the current  (or in your opinion, previous state). You can use the callback in `this.setState( { toDoItems: newToDoItems }, () => console.log( this.state.toDoItems ) )` to validate this

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks so so so much! I really appreciate it. If you wanna make an answer I'll accept it since you were first to respond

Comment: Have you tried to verify if what you want to do somehow works with something else than `console.log`?

Comment: @LongTSQLFiles actually it's a duplicate i just didn't find the correct one to close it with

Comment: @Icepickle Would you prefer me to delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**State update in React is asynchronous**, so you should not expect updated values in the next statement itself. Instead you can try something like(logging updated state in setState callback):

```
    this.setState({
     toDoItems: {newToDoItems},// also i doubt this statement as well, shouldn't it be like:  toDoItems: newToDoItems ? 
    },()=>{
       //callback from state update
       console.log(this.state.toDoItems);
    })
```